# Adding a css file to the <head> element in a jsp file?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have been searching the net for the last hour but I can't see how to add a css file to the `<head>` element of a page.

Say I have a jsp called shopping.jsp. And inside it I conditionally include a jsp tag file called products.tag.

I want products.jsp to specify a css file to add to the head element of the page. How can this be done?

**EDIT**

This code is simplified for the sake of example.

```
// shopping.jsp
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib prefix="t" tagdir="/WEB-INF/tags" %>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

<t:standard_page>
    <jsp:body>
        <t:products product="${product}"/>
    </jsp:body>
</t:standard_page>


// products.tag
// I want to specify a css file in this tag file that will get added to the <head> element of the webpage
<%@tag description="Template for products on the shopping cart page" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@tag import="com.myapp.Product" %>
<%@attribute name="product" required="true" type="com.myapp.Product"%>

<div class="shopping-cart-row">
    <div class="product-name">${product.name}</div>
    <div class="product-quantity">${product.quantity}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Including a simplified version of the JSP might help orient us and answer questions like (1) Does shopping.jsp include the tags for the `<head>` element?  (2) Is products.jsp included from within the `<head>` or `<body>`?

Comment: Added some jsp code. The `<head>` element is actually in the standard_page.tag file.

Answer (score 1):

According to HTML5, [`<style>` elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/style.html#style-context) can appear inside

> Any element that can contain metadata elements, `div`, `noscript`, `section`, `article`, `aside`

so you need not put `<style>` elements inside the `<head>` the way you do with `<link>` elements if you want your page to validate.

```
<style type="text/css">@import url("/path/to/stylesheet.css");</style>
```

from within the body will load the external stylesheet just fine.

If it's way down in the `<body>` or there are any long running non-deferred/async `<script>` elements before it, then those styles may arrive noticably later than styles loaded from the `<head>`.

Comment: So is it possible to add it to the <head>? I am not using HTML5 and I would like all my stylesheets to be added to the `<head>` element rather than appearing in arbitrary parts of the page.

Comment: @sonicboom, you are using HTML5 whether you like it or not, since that is the version of HTML that most modern browser makers consider controlling.  Web framework authors tend to want to be able to flush fixed-size buffers so they tend not to allow element or header hoisting.

Comment: @MikeSamuel — Sorry, but that's completely wrong. The `doctype` is specified by the website, above the HTML opening tag, rather than by the browser.